# Google cloud startup script on custom image

Tags: java, google-compute-engine

I want to start an ubuntu in google cloud. my problem is when I want to run a startup script like:

```
            Metadata.Items item2 = new Metadata.Items();
            item2.setKey("startup-script");
            item2.setValue("my script....");
```

the problem is that my startup script never running. Has anybody idea how can I run startup script on custom image automatically? 
I have preinstalled cloud-init on my image.

Comment: I think this is not Google App Engine but Google Compute Engine. Could you edit the tags? And please, have a look here https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript

Comment: I checked it but the problem is the images in the example is basic google cloud images not a custom one

Answer (score 0):

In the *Google Developers' Console*, go your *Ubuntu instance settings*.

Then add a new Custom Metadata key-value pair.

```
Key: startup-script 
Value: your script or a URL of where to find it
```

Checked it works with own Ubuntu custom image. Try with something simple at the beginning like

```
echo `date` >> /tmp/startup-script
```

Comment: hmm I tried this one but its not working for me. This is why I asking

Comment: Then, the issue must be with your custom image.

Comment: did you installed any specific google package like google-startup-scripts ?

Comment: I didn't create the image, but a colleague who's on holidays this week. Definitely, google-startup-scripts is installed.